# DotNet Neo4JClient error: Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am currently using the Neo4J Client for .Net for a new project. Beforehand I already used the client in other project and tried to reuse my code but came across an error I never had before. *Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied*

I already searched a lot but cant figure out an answer to my problem.
My setup:

- Web API with.NET Framework 4.8
- Neo4JClient at version 4.1.15 installed from NuGet
- Neo4J Desktop with Neo4J Database at version 4.3.1
- Also tested with Neo4J Desktop with Neo4J Database at version 3.5.30

So basically I have a Neo4J Database that contains some nodes with Label "ObjectType" that are connected to nodes with label "Table" via the relationshiptype "IS_CREATED_IN". Now I want to query the objecttypes and the tables.

My C# code is:

```
var q = Client.Cypher
.Match("(node:ObjectType)-[e:IS_CREATED_IN]->(table)")
.Return((node, e, table) => new
{
   node = node.As<Node<string>>()
});
```

With that I always get the error **Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied **.

I changed the type of the nodes from *Node* to *NodeObjectTypeDto*. This works, but I want to create more general methods to use them in a BaseRepository. Therefore I want to use the *Node* Type but cant figure out how I can do that.

```
public class NodeObjectTypeDto
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ENTRYCOUNT { get; set; }
}
```

In my earlier project I used the below setup. There the usage of *node.As<Node>()* worked fine.

- Neo4JClient at version 2.0.0.9
- Neo4J Server with Neo4J Database at version 3.4.1

Here is an excerpt of the returned Raw JSON of Neo4J:

```
{"columns":["node"],"data":[{"row":[{"Description":"MATERIAL","Alias":"MATERIAL","ENTRYCOUNT":16968,"Id":29585,"Name":"MATERIAL"}],"meta":[{"id":62937,"type":"node","deleted":false}]},{"row":[{"Description":"MATERIAL","Alias":"MATERIAL","ENTRYCOUNT":16968,"Id":29585,"Name":"MATERIAL"}],"meta":[{"id":62937,"type":"node","deleted":false}]}]
```

Has anyone an idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `Node<string>` is that all you are getting is the raw JSON, and at that point, you may as well either use a standard REST client (if using `GraphClient`) or the Neo4j.Driver (if using the `BoltGraphClient`) as both of those give you a more 'base' level connection.

Having said that - the `Node<string>` approach should work - and I'm not sure when it stopped working.

At the moment, the only realistic way to get it working would be a PR to allow it to do the conversion, and, if I'm honest, I'm a bit surprised it's not working with the http version as well, as I'm reasonably confident that hasn't been touched.

If that *is* the case, then the other 'reason' might be that Neo4j itself no longer gives the output that can be parsed correctly.

All of these are 'investigation' lines unfortunately, and not 'answers'.

Comment: Thank you Charlotte for your answer! 
I am currently investigating in which version of the Neo4J GraphClient this approach is possible again. I will post here if I find out. 

I think I will stay with my defined type `NodeObjectTypeDto` for the moment.

Comment: My current solution looks like this:

var queryResult = await Client.Cypher.Match("(node:ObjectType)-[e:IS_CREATED_IN]->(table)").Set("node.Neo4JId = id(node)")
.Set("node.Labels = labels(node)")
.Set("table.Neo4JId = id(table)")
.Set("table.Labels = labels(table)")
.Return((node, table) => new
{
ObjectType = node.As<NodeObjectTypeDto>(),
TableDtos = table.CollectAsDistinct<NodeTableDto>()
})
.ResultsAsync;